# value of searchViewController has no member performStoreRequest in swift 3.0

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3

Getting error on screen value of searchViewController has no member performStoreRequest in swift 3.0

[image]

Comment: You should include code in your question, not a screen shot, but the error is pretty clear; Your `SearchViewController` class does not declare a function `performStoreRequest`

Comment: Maybe func `performStoreRequest ` in other extension, then you should add access level `fileprivate` or `public`

Comment: i declare performstoreRequest still getting error